# Does an imageReferenceSku change result an VMSS reimage?

Tags: azure-vm-scale-set

I'm using Azure VMSS.
I've changed imageReferenceSku from 2016 to 2019.
I just want to make sure that this action results a reimaging.
I've read that reimaging deleted unused certificates on the VMSS so I want to make sure it did reimaged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing imageReferenceSku from 2016 to 2019 works like the OS upgrade manually.

From the [docs](http://Azure%20virtual%20machine%20scale%20set%20automatic%20OS%20image%20upgrades), Automatic OS upgrade has the following characteristics:

> The OS Disk of a VM is replaced with the new OS Disk created with
> latest image version. Configured extensions and custom data scripts
> are run, while persisted data disks are retained.

Compare with it, I don't think os upgrading will result in VMSS reimage.

If you reimage a VM, certificates are deleted. Reimaging deletes the entire OS disk.